# Crawlers do not take Robots.txt file from website root BUT takes from web root

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

I've blocked the crawlers to crawl my web root (/var/www/ in my case) with robots.txt. I've robots.txt in /var/www/ and it has the below line in it:
    Disallow /

Now I need one of my subdirectory of the web root(/var/www/mysite.com) to be crawled by crawlers. I've added the robots.txt in that directory and added the virtualhost in the apache to allow this mysite.com to be crawled. BUT the crawlers are still takes the robots.txt from my web root(/var/www) instead of (/var/www/mysite.com).

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only specify one `robots.txt` which goes in your root directory.

More information can be found in the [official documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

> #### Where to put it
>
> The short answer: in the top-level directory of your web server.
>
> The longer answer:
>
> When a robot looks for the "/robots.txt" file for URL, it strips the
>   path component from the URL (everything from the first single slash),
>   and puts "/robots.txt" in its place.
>
> For example, for "http://www.example.com/shop/index.html, it will
>   remove the "/shop/index.html", and replace it with "/robots.txt", and
>   will end up with "http://www.example.com/robots.txt".

Also from the same page (at the bottom) it gives an example of allowing only a certain webpage:

> #### To exclude all files except one
>
> This is currently a bit awkward, as there is no "Allow" field.
>
> The easy way is to put all files to be disallowed into a separate
>   directory, say "stuff", and leave the one file in the level above this
>   directory:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /~joe/stuff/
```

> Alternatively you can
>   explicitly disallow all disallowed pages:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /~joe/junk.html 
Disallow: /~joe/foo.html 
Disallow: /~joe/bar.html
```